# How to calculate the differential cross section in the center-of-mass frame for a process $AB \rightarrow CD$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics

I'm trying to do Exercise 4.2 in Halzen, Martin's "Quarks and Leptons"

> In the center of mass frame for the process $AB \rightarrow CD $, show that
>
> $$\begin{array} { c } { d Q = \frac { 1 } { 4 \pi ^ { 2 } } \frac { p
>  _ { f } } { 4 \sqrt { s } } d \Omega } \\ { F = 4 p _ { i } \sqrt { s } } \end{array}
> $$
>
> and hence the differential cross section is
>   $$\left. \frac { d \boldsymbol { \sigma } } { d \Omega } \right| _ { \mathrm { cm } }= \frac { 1 } { 64 \pi ^ { 2 } s }\frac { p _ { f } } { p _ { i } } |\mathrm{M}|^2$$

Here $dQ$ is the Lorentz invariant phase space factor
$$d Q = ( 2 \pi ) ^ { 4 } \delta ^ { ( 4 ) } \left( p _ { C } + p _ { D } - p _ { A } - p _ { B } \right) \frac { d ^ { 3 } p _ { C } } { ( 2 \pi ) ^ { 3 } 2 E _ { C } } \frac { d ^ { 3 } p _ { D } } { ( 2 \pi ) ^ { 3 } 2 E _ { D } }$$

So in the solution, they said:

$$\begin{aligned} d Q & = \frac { 1 } { 4 \pi ^ { 2 } } \frac { d ^ { 3 } p _ { C } } { 2 E _ { C } } \frac { d ^ { 3 } p _ { D } } { 2 E _ { D } } \delta ^ { ( 4 ) } \left( p _ { A } + p _ { B } - p _ { C } - p _ { D } \right) \\ & = \frac { 1 } { 4 \pi ^ { 2 } } \frac { d ^ { 3 } p _ { C } } { 2 E _ { C } } \frac { 1 } { 2 E _ { D } } \delta \left( E _ { A } + E _ { B } - E _ { C } - E _ { D } \right) \end{aligned}$$

I do not understand this step at all! Can anyone tell me how they derive it like that? Thank you!

Comment: A hint: $$ \delta^{(4)} (p_A+p_B - p_C - p_D)$$  can be separated into $$\delta (E_A+E_B-E_C-E_D)\cdot \delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}_A+\vec{p}_B-\vec{p}_C-\vec{p}_D)$$.

Comment: I honestly don't see it yet.  $p_D$ is four-momentum right? How can its differential suddenly combie with a delta function and vanish both?

Comment: $p_D$ is a four momentum, but $\mathrm{d}^3 p_D$ is an integration over the components of the 3-momentum $\vec{p}_D$, all that's missing is a delta function integral identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to find the differential cross-section for the process $AB 
\rightarrow CD$ in the center-of-mass frame. As you have mentioned,

\begin{align}
dQ =(2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}(p_C+p_D-p_A-p_B)\frac{d^3\mathbf{p}_C}{(2\pi)^3 2E_C}\frac{d^3\mathbf{p}_D}{(2\pi)^3 2E_D} \\
\end{align}
Here, the role of the 4-momentum dirac delta function is to ensure 4-momentum conservation in the final calculation. Now, separating the energy and 3-momentum delta functions,
\begin{align}
dQ = \frac{1}{4\pi^2} \frac{1}{4 E_C E_D}\delta(E_C+E_D-E_A-E_B)\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{p}_C+\mathbf{p}_D-\mathbf{p}_A-\mathbf{p}_B) d^3\mathbf{p}_C d^3\mathbf{p}_D.
\end{align}

By choosing the CM frame, we made the restriction that $\mathbf{p}_B = -\mathbf{p}_A$. However, this choice doesn't make any restriction on $\mathbf{p}_C$ and $\mathbf{p}_D$. As of now (i.e., before the integration over phase space), they are still integration variables. So,

\begin{align}
dQ & = \frac{1}{4\pi^2} \frac{1}{4 E_C E_D}\delta(E_C+E_D-E_A-E_B)\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{p}_C+\mathbf{p}_D) d^3\mathbf{p}_C d^3\mathbf{p}_D.
\end{align}

But finally when we do the integration over the phase space to obtain the cross-section $\sigma$, the integration over $d^3\mathbf{p}_D$ along with the delta function $\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{p}_C+\mathbf{p}_D)$ in the integrand vanish together implying $\mathbf{p}_D = -\mathbf{p}_C$ (ensuring 3-momentum conservation). Considering this, we can write

\begin{align}
dQ & = \frac{1}{4\pi^2} \frac{1}{4 E_C E_D}\delta(E_C+E_D-E_A-E_B) d^3\mathbf{p}_C.
\end{align}